# What is this IC marked "M JT"?

Tags: identification

This IC is on a breakout board for a SIM868 chip. It is on the GPS antenna signal line, just before the U.FL connector.

It has 5 pins, 3 that are connected to ground, 1 to the signal, and 1 (I think) to power.

What is this chip and what does it do?

Zoomed-in photo (IC's markings are visible):
[image: Zoomed in photo]

Zoomed-out photo (all connections are visible):
[image: Zoomed out photo]

Comment: It is most likely an LNA.

Comment: looks something like this LNA http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/302/BGU6104-840139.pdf

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 That looks like a viable answer and I would love to accept it.

Comment: The manufacturer logo's the giveaway here -- the SAW filter answer is the correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks something like same package and application as LNA http://mouser.com/ds/2/302/BGU6104-840139.pdf

Answer (score 8):

it is a saw filter, to remove noise on the gps antenna line

3 gnd pins
1 input
1 output

see following for spec
http://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/productdata/8797690593310/DS-SAFEB1G57KE0F00.pdf?1453347007000

Nick